# My Character Keeps Going Diagonal when i start the Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm making a Survival Game in First Person and this is my code for the Player. But the error is the layer keeps laying down. Even tho there is no gravity. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, -90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Mathf.Clamp function you use -90 two times, thus setting the xRotation to -90 every time. You propably want to Clamp it between -90 and 90.

Edit: xRotation is reduced using mouseY every frame, but it is never reset. This means, that moving the mouse to the right will cause the camera to continue rotating even after the mouse has stopped moving. You propably want to set xRotation using -mouseY (or plus? not sure) instead of reducing it by mouseY. This should make the camera stop spinning while the mouse is not moved.

Comment: Thanks ill definitely try it